# JDBC exception with sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting below error while connecting Linux Oracle server from Windows in Java (JDBC), may I know how to solve this error.

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: What database are you using (MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL, PostgreSQL, ...)? Did you set up the server to use SSL? Using what certificate?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c

Comment: Then edit question and tag it.

Comment: The error indicates that it can't establish trust for the SSL certificate used. You may need to add the SSL certificate to your trust store.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Security whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) for more information and instructions.